# Wireguard VPN: http server on peer doesn't respond

Tags: networking, vpn, iptables, wireguard

I'm trying to set up a Wireguard VPN for accessing services running on my home server (behind router and ISP NAT) and some other computers.

The peers are:

- Wireguard bounce server (A), a VPS.
- Another VPS (B) that has some services running bound to the wireguard interface.
- Laptop (C) on my home network.
- Laptop (D) at work.
- My home server (E) that connects to my home WiFi via another router in client mode.

Almost everything works nicely:

- I can access services on A and B from my laptops.
- I can route traffic from laptops through A (hiding my IP).
- I can access services on my home server (E) when using home wifi IP address (not VPN).
- I can ping from anywhere to E.
- I can send messages via netcat from anywhere to E and back.

What doesn't work: I can't access web services running on my home server E via browser from either C or D laptops.

Bounce server (A) config (relevant part):

```
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens2 -j MASQUERADE;
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens2 -j MASQUERADE;
```

I tried to do `tcpdump` on E and it looks like it's trying to respond, but it can't. The browser is stuck on "waiting for server" in the meantime.

```
alice# tcpdump -n -i wg0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wg0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
21:01:57.709120 IP 10.100.100.3.60880 > 10.100.100.5.9091: Flags [SEW], seq 3428632112, win 65535, options [mss 1380,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 786593373 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
21:01:57.709172 IP 10.100.100.5.9091 > 10.100.100.3.60880: Flags [S.E], seq 172168014, ack 3428632113, win 64296, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 4134630026 ecr 786593373,nop,wscale 7], length 0
21:01:57.814616 IP 10.100.100.3.60880 > 10.100.100.5.9091: Flags [.], ack 1, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 786593482 ecr 4134630026], length 0
21:01:57.816591 IP 10.100.100.3.60880 > 10.100.100.5.9091: Flags [P.], seq 1:445, ack 1, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 786593482 ecr 4134630026], length 444
21:01:57.816626 IP 10.100.100.5.9091 > 10.100.100.3.60880: Flags [.], ack 445, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 4134630133 ecr 786593482], length 0
21:01:57.816754 IP 10.100.100.5.9091 > 10.100.100.3.60880: Flags [P.], seq 1:220, ack 445, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 4134630133 ecr 786593482], length 219
21:01:58.255972 IP 10.100.100.5.9091 > 10.100.100.3.60880: Flags [P.], seq 1:220, ack 445, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 4134630572 ecr 786593482], length 219
21:01:58.895991 IP 10.100.100.5.9091 > 10.100.100.3.60880: Flags [P.], seq 1:220, ack 445, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 4134631212 ecr 786593482], length 219
21:02:00.175994 IP 10.100.100.5.9091 > 10.100.100.3.60880: Flags [P.], seq 1:220, ack 445, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 4134632492 ecr 786593482], length 219
21:02:02.895994 IP 10.100.100.5.9091 > 10.100.100.3.60880: Flags [P.], seq 1:220, ack 445, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 4134635212 ecr 786593482], length 219
```

It looks like `10.100.100.5:9091` is trying to respond, but it keeps retrying to do that, and `10.100.100.3` keeps waiting for the response. So the packets reach E but can't go back for some reason.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @GGGforce I have the same issue, have you ever resolved this?